# What should i do so that the animation changes the position of the element forever?

Tags: html, css

Every time the animation completes its duration... It  returns to its original position... How to solve that problem? I want that my element keeps the position it required after animation without using Java.

Comment: Frankly... I am a beginner and I am trying to understand the concept of animation in HTML. This is a conceptual question... but I would be grateful if anybody could solve this problem.       
P.S. I have tried to increase the animation-duration manifolds .. but I know that it was silly :P

Comment: StackOverflow is for answering specific technical questions on a well formed problem, so that others can benefit from understanding the answer. It's not a general tutorial site or a way of getting others' opinions on how to do something. You might be better off looking for tutorials through a search engine.

Comment: Moreover in your question you talk about `Java` but you have not tagged with it. Did you meant `JavaScript`? which is different from `Java`

Answer (score 0):

Use animation-fill-mode property

```
animation-fill-mode:forwards;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp